# How can we verify data is saved into keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain

I'm using the [UICKeyChainStore](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore) framework to save data to keychain.

How can I verify that the data is saved to the keychain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data back after storing in this way:

`NSString *name = [UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@username" service:@"username"];`

and then compare the strings to make sure that the value is saved

Alternatively, you can also use the following library. https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641

Comment: Thanks will check out the library.

Answer (score 0):

UICKeyChainStore's `setString forKey` method returns the bool value , You can add a check on it.

```
BOOL result = [UICKeyChainStore setString:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
    if (result) {
        NSLog(@"data saved successfully");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"problem in saving");
    }
```